# Is this trick valid in proving that $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$; $f(x)=x^3$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I wish to show that for $f:(0,\infty)$, with $f(x) = x^3$, is continuous for all $a\in(0,\infty)$.

I wondered whether the following trick is valid?

Notice that $|x^3-a^3|=|x-a|\cdot|x^2+ax+a^2|$. Now since $a,x$ are strictly positive, surely $x^2+ax+a^2<x^2+2ax+a^2=(x+a)^2$. Then $|x^3-a^3|<|x-a|(x+a)^2<\delta(x+a)^2$. Taking $\delta<1$, we see that $x+a<2a+1$.

Hence given $\epsilon>0$, take $\delta:=\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{(2a+1)^2})$. Then for all $x\in(0,\infty)$ with $0<|x-a|<\delta$ we have $$|x^3-a^3|<\delta(x+a)^2<\delta(2a+1)^2\leq\epsilon.$$

Have I made a mistake or was this a valid 'trick' in this particular context?

Comment: You need $|x+a| < |2a+1|$, but otherwise looks good!

Comment: Usually, one does not need to prove such property from the first principle. Do you know that product of two continuous functions (with the same domain) is continuous?

Comment: @Dzoooks but $x$ and $a$ are strictly positive.  So $x+a > 0$ and $2a+1 > 0$.  ... anyway, is valid.  May need to spell out why $|x-a|<\delta < 1$ means $-1 < x-a < 1$ so $a-1 < x < a+1$ and $x+a < 2a + 1$.  Or not.  Maybe I'm just being a little sluggish this afternoon.

Comment: @fleablood  No, $x$ is not strictly positive. $|x-a|<1$ for $a > 0$ implies only $x> -1$.

Comment: @Jack you are correct. Usually I would just use more easily applicable results. However, this question stems from a past-exam question asking us to prove the result in question from first principles. My approach was not included in the suggested solutions, so wished to check that it was correct.

Comment: @Dzoooks Thank you for your reply. I had considered whether I'd have to keep $|2a+1|$ instead of $2a+1$. But do we not know that $x$ cannot be less than $0$ since such an $x$ is not even included in the domain? I.e the definition of continuous is $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that for all $x\in(0,\infty)$ with $|x-a|<\delta$ .... etc. Does this not exclude $x<0$, so I would not need to worry about using $|\cdot|$ in this case? Clarification would be very helpful!

Comment: Since your argument says for all $x\in(0,\infty)$, you do not need to worry about the case when $x>0$.

Comment: @Dzoooks.  $x$ and $a$ are strictly positive because they are two points in the  domain $f$ which is $(0, \infty)$.  I wasn't basing this one *anything* to do with $x$ and $a$ being within vicinity of each other.

Comment: @Benjamin Because the domain is strictly positive we know $x,a, x+a, 2a + 1$ are all positive and $|x+1| = x+1 < 2a + 1 = |2a+1|$. ... But it *is* odd that that is part of the question.  If we had had $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as $f(x)= x^3$ then $f$ is still continuous everywhere and your trick would still be valid.  But *then* you'd have to show $|x+a| < |2a+1|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you are proving continuity, instead of $0<|x-a|<\delta$, you need $|x-a|<\delta$ in your proof.
- all you need is a bound on the quantity $(x+a)^2$ for $x$ near $a$.
- What you did is OK but I would rewrite it in a slightly different way as follows.

---

Let $a$ be a fixed real number. Let $\epsilon>0$. We want to find a $\delta>0$ so that for all $x>0$ with $|x-a|<\delta$,
$$
|x^3-a^3|<\epsilon.\tag{1}
$$

Observe that since $x,a>0$,
$$
|x^3-a^3|=|x-a|\cdot|x^2+ax+a^2|=|x-a|(x^2+ax+a^2)\le |x-a|(x+a)^2\tag{2}
$$

On the other hand, for $x>0$ with $|x-a|<1$,
$$
(x+a)^2=(x-a+a)^2\leq 2(x-a)^2 +2a^2\le 2+2a^2\tag{3}
$$ 
Taking $\delta=\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+a^2)})$, we conclude from (2) and (3) that 
$$
|x^3-a^3|\leq\delta\cdot 2(1+a^2)\leq \epsilon.
$$

---

[Added:]
You do *not* need to write $|x^2+ax+a^2|=x^2+ax+a^2$. Simply use 
$$
|x^2+ax+a^2|\leq |x|^2+|ax|+a^2
$$
and you can easily bound each of the quantities on the right for $x$ with $|x-a|<1$.

Such approach would give you a proof of continuity of $x^3$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from first principles, then using elementary properties of parabolas, note that

for $\delta<a/2,$ we have

$|x^3-a^3|=|x-a|\cdot|x^2+ax+a^2|\le |x-a|\cdot ((a+\delta)^2+a\delta+a^2)\le \frac{21}{4}\cdot |x-a|$

so we may take $\delta =\min(a/2,\epsilon/6).$